# Cut image to fit in image view

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a UIImageView with frame 320x240.

```
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 240)];
imgView.image = [self getImageFromServer:100];
```

I have tried many ways bit no one resulted for me.

The app loads images from server, but some of them are 320x320.

What i must to cut the image received? It's to cut, does'n mater if someone is going to appear without head.

Regards

Comment: Look into the view's `contentMode` - specifically `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
imgView.clipsToBounds = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `contentMode` as `Center` if you want to keep always the size or you can resize untill it fits and then crop using the `Scale Aspect Fit` contend mode. You also need to clip the subviews.

You can do both actions via Interface Builder:

Setting the content mode:

[image]

Setting clip SubViews to YES:

[image]

Or programmatically:

```
//set the contentMode
imgView.contentMode = .contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;

//set clip subviews
test.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.Maybe this can solve the problem :)

Comment: @Miguel did you managed to make it work the way you wanted? :)